# Pivot without aggregation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am trying to figure out how to pivot column to row without aggregation.

I have a table with Account, Company Name and Company %. I am trying to pivot so that all companies info with respect to that account are on the same row. There isn't a limit on how many companies an account could have and I will need to include all companies.

Currently:

| Account | Company Name | Company % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Company A | Company A% |
| 1 | Company B | Company B% |
| 2 | Company B | Company B% |
| 3 | Company A | Company A% |
| 3 | Company B | Company B% |
| 3 | Company K | Company K% |
| 3 | Company W | Company W% |

Expected Results:

| Account | Company 1 | Company 1% | Company 2 | Company 2% | Company 3 | Company 3% | Company 4 | Company 4% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Company A | Company A% | Company B | Company B% |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | Company B | Company B% |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | Company A | Company A% | Company B | Company B% | Company K | Company K% | Company W | Company W% |

Comment: In HTML? SQL? What is the question?

Comment: Pivot in SQL. Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS? e.g. Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle

Comment: Also, does it need to be a true pivot with actual columns, or would something like `listagg` be acceptable? e.g. `2, "Company B, Company B%"`

Comment: Just curious what's wrong with aggregation?

Comment: You're translating groups of between 1 and 4 rows into 1 row per group.  That, by definition, is aggregation.  Even if you end up with `MAX( {NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Something'} ) == 'Something'`, that is still done via aggregation.

Comment: @EdmCoff Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2016. I need true Pivot

Comment: @SQLROOKIE - Please feel free to upvote and/or accept any answers that have helped you, on this and your other questions.

Comment: @MatBailie Good to know. Most examples I saw have to do with number aggregation

Comment: @MatBailie I will test it out and let you know. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any modern implementation of SQL has `ROW_NUMBER()` and that can be used for what you want.

It still uses `MAX()` to collapse multiple rows in to single rows, but it is being used as `pick the one value that isn't NULL`.

There is no sane reason to avoid its use.

```
WITH
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    yourTable.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account ORDER BY company_name)  AS account_row_id
  FROM
    yourTable
)
SELECT
  account,
  MAX(CASE WHEN account_row_id = 1 THEN company_name END)   AS company_name_1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN account_row_id = 1 THEN company_pct  END)   AS company_pct_1,

  MAX(CASE WHEN account_row_id = 2 THEN company_name END)   AS company_name_2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN account_row_id = 2 THEN company_pct  END)   AS company_pct_2,

  MAX(CASE WHEN account_row_id = 3 THEN company_name END)   AS company_name_3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN account_row_id = 3 THEN company_pct  END)   AS company_pct_3,

  MAX(CASE WHEN account_row_id = 4 THEN company_name END)   AS company_name_4,
  MAX(CASE WHEN account_row_id = 4 THEN company_pct  END)   AS company_pct_4
FROM
  sorted
GROUP BY
  account
ORDER BY
  account
```

Comment: Sorry, it took me a long time to test this but it worked. Thank you so much!
I tried to upvote but it said i need 15 reputation points. Also how do i accept this as the answer?